# Capture partial part of canvas to use it as Bitmap

Tags: android, android-canvas

i am working on one stuff in which i want to use some part of the canvas as bitmap

. here i have attached on image for that . **i want a bitmap  core of rectangle** (which has wight  Stork)

here is a Algorithm of my program .

1: create a canvas .

2: draw a color picker on canvas .

3: draw a rectangle on a canvas.

now i want to use this rectangle as a bitmap ..

so is there any **way to capture a bitmap using a canvas**  ?
(i heard  about Picture class to capture a canvas , i don't know its relevant to this scenario  )

[image: enter image here]  .

Comment: Why not draw everything on a Bitmap first, then draw the Bitmap to the canvas, and then you can just clip the rectangle from the original Bitmap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All canvas is is a wrapper to a bitmap that exposes useful drawing functions. So you can create a canvas with a bitmap, then call createBitmap() on that bitmap to just get the small rectangle. Below is an outline of the code.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(/*screen width*/, /*screen height*/);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
// . . .
// Draw color picker
// . . .
Bitmap selectedRectangle = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, /*x*/, /*y*/, /*rectWidth*/, /*rectHeight*/);
```

Comment: But the rectangle that you create is wrt the co-ordinate system of the bitmap itself and not the portion of the original bitmap that is drawn on the canvas or screen, right? For ex: if you zoom out the original bitmap (by scaledetector) and then try to get the portion of the of the bitmap, will that correspond to the original bitmap co-ords or the zoomed co-ords that we see on the screen?